# Selecting an option from a javascript dropdown menu on Internet Explorer with VBA

Tags: javascript, excel, vba

I need to select an option from a javascript dropdown menu on IE with VBA, as the tittle says. In the code below, I have to select the option "SAO1636 - SAOJJ231C - Kontik Franstur" (Option value = "279-32")

The HTML code (The code continues to other dropdown menus, but only this one is necessary):

```
<table border="0" class="gridsubbox" style="background-color: #ffffff" width="706">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="border-top: #919b9c 0px solid" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="9" style="width:15%;"></td>
                    <td align="right" class="Celula" style="width:10%;"><span class="u">T</span>AM</td>
                    <td style="width:75%;"><select name="FormAcessosDisponiveis1$cbTAM" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'FormAcessosDisponiveis1$cbTAM\',\'\')', 0)" id="FormAcessosDisponiveis1_cbTAM" class="CamposEdit2" style="width:300px;">
    <option selected="selected" value="46-35">RIO2460 - RIO2460 - UTILIZAR SABRE</option>
    <option value="84-83">SSA2726 - SSA2726 - Kontik (Posto BR)</option>
    <option value="147-116">RIO3257 - RIOJJ237H - Petrobras Rio</option>
    <option value="175-172">SAO3586 - SAOJJ2836 - Leroy Merlin</option>
    <option value="182-187">SSA2823 - SSAJJ21BV - Maquina de Vendas</option>
    <option value="189-244">SSA2837 - SSAJJ21BZ - Bahia Minera&#231;&#227;o</option>
    <option value="202-30">SSA197 - SSAJJ218B - Kontik Franstur</option>
    <option value="205-258">SAO4018 - SAOJJ21Q3 - Novo Nordisk</option>
    <option value="225-539">RIO2758 - RIOJJ219X - Transpetro</option>
    <option value="230-306">SAO4227 - SAOJJ21V2 - Siemens</option>
    <option value="231-288">SAO4228 - SAOJJ21V3 - Skanska</option>
    <option value="237-333">RIO3504 - RIOJJ21J1 - Prudential</option>
    <option value="241-313">SAO4231 - SAOJJ21V6 - Kontik Net</option>
    <option value="244-317">SAO4233 - SAOJJ21V8 - Kontik Y</option>
    <option value="246-337">SSA2872 - SSAJJ21D0 - Engepack</option>
    <option value="247-332">SAO4232 - SAOJJ21V7 - Evonik</option>
    <option value="256-29">SSA75 - SSAJJ211Q - Kontik Franstur</option>
    <option value="257-107">SSA2776 - SSAJJ216S - BR Distribuidora SSA</option>
    <option value="259-488">SSA2912 - SSAJJ2133 - Kontik Franstur</option>
    <option value="260-153">SAO3585 - SAOJJ2837 - Angeloni</option>
    <option value="261-183">SSA2815 - SSAJJ2202 - Tam Operadora SSA</option>
    <option value="262-131">SSA2803 - SSAJJ217E - Celpe</option>
    <option value="263-118">RIO3256 - RIOJJ237G - Banco BBM</option>
    <option value="264-94">QOC142 - SAOJJ224K - Bradesco</option>
    <option value="265-132">SSA2802 - SSAJJ217D - Cosern</option>
    <option value="266-127">SAO3474 - SAOJJ258S - Eli Lilly</option>
    <option value="268-130">SAO3338 - SAOJJ2561 - Odebrecht</option>
    <option value="270-99">SAO3302 - SAOJJ255L - Arno</option>
    <option value="271-136">SAO3507 - SAOJJ259R - Reckitt Benckiser</option>
    <option value="273-84">SAO3078 - SAOJJ249W - Unibanco</option>
    <option value="274-135">RIO3297 - RIOJJ238F - Webb Negocios</option>
    <option value="275-128">SSA2775 - SSAJJ216R - Sala Vip Aeroporto</option>
    <option value="276-174">RIO3327 - RIOJJ246H - Kontik Franstur</option>
    <option value="277-109">SAO3400 - SAOJJ256T - Igreja</option>
    <option value="278-538">SAO4665 - SAOJJ257O - Videolar</option>
    <option value="279-32">SAO1636 - SAOJJ231C - Kontik Franstur</option>
    <option value="287-368">SAO4526 - SAOJJ22CN - Almart</option>
    <option value="289-334">RIO3503 - RIOJJ21J0 - BR Distribuidora</option>
    <option value="294-373">RIO3506 - RIOJJ21J3 - HRT OIL And GAS</option>
    <option value="299-379">SAO4527 - SAOJJ22CP - Camargo Correa</option>
    <option value="300-399">SAO4605 - SAOJJ210Q - Louis Dreyfus</option>
    <option value="312-393">SAO4600 - SAOJJ22E2 - TNT</option>
    <option value="314-394">SAO4603 - SAOJJ22E3 - Danone</option>
    <option value="316-395">SAO4604 - SAOJJ22E4- Tavex</option>
    <option value="319-403">SAO4606 - SAOJJ22E5 - Raizen</option>
    <option value="325-409">RIO3567 - RIOJJ21KR - Amil</option>
    <option value="333-428">SAO4633 - SAOJJ22EH - Hypermarcas</option>
    <option value="335-430">SAO4525 - SAOJJ22CM - Ultragaz</option>
    <option value="344-421">SAO4230 - SAOJJ21V5 - Liquigas</option>
    <option value="354-483">SAO4664 - SAOJJ22FB - Bosch</option>
    <option value="364-500">SAO4695 - SAOJJ21NQ - Amadeus</option>
    <option value="365-502">RIO3569 - RIOJJ21KP - Anglo American RIO</option>
    <option value="372-511">SAO4696 - SAOJJ21NS - Sandvik</option>
    <option value="384-243">SAO3905 - SAO3905 - ZF do Brasil</option>

</select></td>
                </tr>
```

Things I've tried on VBA:

```
ie.Document.getElementsByName("FormAcessosDisponiveis1$cbTAM").Value = "SAO1636 - SAOJJ231C - Kontik Franstur"
----------------
ie.Document.getElementbyID("FormAcessosDisponiveis1_cbTAM").Value = "SAO1636 - SAOJJ231C - Kontik Franstur"
----------------
ie.Document.getElementsByName("FormAcessosDisponiveis1$cbTAM").Value = "279-32"
----------------
ie.Document.getElementbyID("FormAcessosDisponiveis1_cbTAM").focus
ie.Document.getElementbyID("FormAcessosDisponiveis1_cbTAM").selectedindex = 5 'the number is not correct.. I just wanted to change the dropdown menu at this point
```

Anyway, I've looked in a bunch of websites and I'm not being able to solve this. I'd really appreciate if anyone could help me with this

Thank you for helping me

System Info
IE9 / EXCEL 2010 / WIN 7